# Iterated expectation

Tags: probability

Can anyone give a hand with the second step in this part of the solution. I'm in the process of finding the Covariance of Y1 and Y2. [image]

I would have thought that E(Y1Y2|Y2=y2) would be E(Y1y2)=y2E(Y1) but here it seems it equals y2E(Y1|Y2=y2).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simple reason why it must be written $y_2 {\rm E}[Y_1 \mid Y_2 = y_2]$ is because $Y_1$ and $Y_2$ are not independent random variables.  the distribution of $Y_1$ given $Y_2 = y_2$ is different than the marginal (unconditional) distribution of $Y_1$, so their expectations will also differ.  That is what is stated in the second to last line:  the conditional distribution is normal, but the mean is dependent on $y_2$.  The marginal distribution of $Y_1$ is not.

Comment: Sorry but it seems i'm getting confused by the notation. I understand Y1 and Y2 are dependent which means E(Y1Y2)=/=E(Y1)E(Y2), so if you could go through the notation step by step it would be very useful.